# sorting matrix in matlab based on another vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector

I have a 2D matrix and want to sort rows and columns based on two other vectors i.e. one for ordering rows another for ordering columns in MATLAB

Example: A (Matrix to order)

```
0 1 2 3 4
1 1 8 9 7
2 3 4 6 2
3 1 2 0 8
```

Row Vector (Order for sorting rows of matrix A)

```
1
4
2
3
```

And column vector

```
1 5 4 2 3
```

Modified A

```
0   4   3   1   2
3   8   0   1   2
1   7   9   1   8
2   2   6   3   4
```

Comment: Indexing in Matlab starts at 1, your index vectors will return an error in their current format.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
ModifiedA=A(RowVector,ColumnVector);
```

**Note**: Matab's indexing starts at `1` not at `0`, adapt your indexing vectors accordingly.

Comment: Actually reading the code makes more sense than the problem description... pretty sad that it takes an answer to clarify what the OP is asking - +1.

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB, you can use the second output of `sort` to get the 1-based indexes that MATLAB is looking for (in this case you could have just added 1, but using `sort` works even if the row and column vectors are not consecutive).

```
[~,rowIdx] = sort(rowVector);
[~,colIdx] = sort(colVector);
```

And then you can apply the indexing operation to the matrix:

```
modifiedA = A(rowIdx, colIdx);
```

Comment: There is no need to call sort on those vectors. The OP has already provided which order each dimension needs to be ordered in so sorting is superfluous.