# Permute the Matrix with Given Index

Tags: matlab, matrix

Given A is symmetry matrix with size n and

```
A = 
         1   2   3   4   5              % The Position

    1   [0   5   2   4   1
    2    5   0   3   0   2
    3    2   3   0   0   0
    4    4   0   0   0   5
    5    1   2   0   5   0]
```

B is a row vector that permute the matrix A row and column

```
B = [2   4   1   5   3]
```

The output that I want is

```
C = 
         2   4   1   5   3              % The New Position given by Matrix B

    2   [0   0   5   2   3
    4    0   0   4   5   0
    1    5   4   0   1   2
    5    2   5   1   0   0
    3    3   0   2   0   0]
```

I can get the output by using simple for loop

```
index = [2,4,1,5,3];
C = zeros(5,5);
for i = 1:5
    for j = 1:5

        % Position of in square matrix n
        % (i,j) = (i-1)*n + j

        C(i,j) = A((index(i)-1)*5+index(j));    
    end
end
```

However, if I want to permute a matrix with size 80x80, then I need to run 1600 times in order to get the output.
Is there any simple trick to do it instead of using for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to rearrange your matrices as follows:

```
C = A(index,index);
```

This rearranges each dimension according to the index variable independently.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar,feel sorry about that. He is correct, just because of my typo, then get another output.

Comment: A similar question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070670/sorting-matrix-in-matlab-based-on-another-vector/27070777 - The question poster of that question should learn from this OP this OP has stated in a more eloquent manner on what is required.  BTW +1 for you MrAzzaman!